# Resize NSImage without losing its properties

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I'm working on an mac application and I work with images. The quality and the ICC profile are really important. Sometimes I need to resize the images because I send them to a server and they cant be too heavy.

I dont have problem with the resizing itself, but I use a copy of the image and I lose the ICC profile : for exemple I got a sRGB image, but after the resize it takes the profile of the screen, and I want to keep the sRGB profile.

```
    -(NSData*)resizeImage: (NSSize)newSize { // I calcul newSize before and the values are good
    NSImage *smallImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: newSize];
    [smallImage lockFocus];
    [image setSize: newSize]; //image is the image I want to resize
    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
    [image drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
    [smallImage unlockFocus];
    return ([self returnImageAsJpeg:smallImage]);
}
```

And here's the

> -(NSData *) returnImageAsJpeg:(NSImage *)smallImage

method :

```
-(NSData *)returnImageAsJpeg:(NSImage *)smallImage {
    NSData *imageData = [smallImage TIFFRepresentation];
    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];
    NSNumber *compressionFactor = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6];
    NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:compressionFactor forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
    imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:imageProps];
    return (imageData);
}
```

I know the code is not really clean, but my question is : how can resize a NSImage without losing its properties. Here I make a copy in smallImage and I use it, but the properties are loss.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Hey there, did you solved it? We have the exact same issue!